# How to ask for more Options at a specific slot value in the Alexa Dialog Model?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I try to develop an Alexa-Skill and have one understanding problem within the dialog-builder.
I ask the User about a Store. I have add a Slot "getStore" with a Slot Type "stores" in my Intent. The Slot Type "stores" contains all stores. Almost all stores are are unique according to their selection. But at two Stores, I need more Information I would like to ask the User.
For Example the User says "Store A", the Slot is filled. But if the User says "Store B" I would like to aks "Did you mean Store B1 or Store B2?" 
I can not add the 2 Variants of Store B in the Slot Type because Users doesn´t know about them.

How can I realize this behavior to inquire about certain values of my Slot Type?

I have already tried the example for the decision tree from the alexa rep (https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-decision-tree). Here this special case does not happen. An example would probably help me to understand...

Thanks a lot!